# position relative but fixed header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position, responsive

I need to have following Header in relative position like here:
[image]

But I want to be the header fixed, when scrolling content, so i tried `position: fixed.

Now the problem is that it looks like that:
[image]

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: So, to clarify - is your problem that your now-fixed header is always covering the content at the top?

Comment: You need to share some code here so we can help

Comment: Give the content some top padding the heighrt of the header.

Answer (score 1):

If your topbar's height is known, add the same width as top position to your content, look at the code or check the fiddle:

```
<div class ="topbar">

</div>
<div class="content">
<p>first line</p>
<p>abc</p>
<p>abc</p>
.
.
.
<p>abc</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.topbar{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#000;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -2px gray;
}
.content{
  position: relative;
  top:60px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmz25qxc/2/)

Comment: Yes that would be the solution. But now the problem is that the pink div covers the shadow of the header...

Comment: I edited the answer and the fiddle to include the shadow

Answer (score 0):

Add a `margin-top` setting equal to the height of your header to the content container (i.e. the element that currently is overlapped by the fixed header)